# SliverAppBar title doesn't fade if style applied in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

I want to have the title in my SliverAppBar fade in the default way however it stops working once I apply style to the text. You can see how it behave with and without TextStyle. Nothing else changes.

[No style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YPkS.gif)

[Style applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgLMO.gif)

Here's the code with style applied:

```dart
class FeedScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 static const routeName = "/feed_screen";


@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ViewModelBuilder<WhosHereScreenViewModel>.reactive(
       disposeViewModel: false,
       initialiseSpecialViewModelsOnce: true,
       viewModelBuilder: () => locator<WhosHereScreenViewModel>(),
       builder: (context, model, child) {
         return Scaffold(
           backgroundColor: Colors.white,
           body: model.isBusy == true
               ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
               : CustomScrollView(slivers: [
                   SliverAppBar(
                     brightness: Brightness.light,
                     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                     title: Text(
                       'miit',
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontFamily: 'Changa',
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                           fontSize: 36.0,
                           color: Colors.black87),
                     ),
                     titleSpacing: -4.0,
                     leading: IconButton(
                       icon: Image.asset('assets/images/new_logo.png'),
                       onPressed: () {},
                     ),
                     floating: true,
                     actions: [
                       Padding(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                         //TODO build filter functionality
                         child: IconButton(
                             icon: Icon(Mdi.accountDetailsOutline,
                                 color: Colors.black87, size: 30.0),
                             onPressed: null),
                       )
                     ],
                   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass text style not in Text widget in title, but in titleTextStyle.

```
title: Text('miit'),
titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Changa',
fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
fontSize: 36.0,
color: Colors.black87),
```